# I'm unable to upload a file whose name has a space in it to Google Cloud Storage using Python. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to Python and Google Cloud. Using Flask I have created a web page where a user can choose a file from their computer and upload it to a GCS bucket that I have already created. I'm following [Google's documentation example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) which uses the Google Python API library. I'm able to upload files whose names are just a single word, like 'image' but if my file is named 'image one' then I get the following error- 
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image one.jpg'

Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET'  , 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        gcs_upload(f.filename)

def gcs_upload(filename):
    storage_client = storage.Client()   # instantiate a client
    bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket_name')
    blob=bucket.blob(filename)      # file name at the destination should be the same
    blob.upload_from_filename(filename)     # file to be uploaded

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

If I'm writing a production level application then I would want a user to upload a file even if it has spaces in its name.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide code for the question at hand.

Comment: Hi @YaakovBressler just added the code

Comment: This may seem obvious, but are you sure there is an actual `image one.jpg` file in the working directory of the script (when that line gets executed)? Because the error message seems to indicate that this isn't a problem with the cloud stuff, but with opening the local file.

Comment: If it is possible you may try renaming the file replacing all whitespaces with underscores "_" or some other character. See if that works for you.

Comment: Does `image\ one.jpg` work?

Comment: @snatchysquid it worked when I replaced spaces with _ before uploading. The answer by Happy-Monad to use the secure_filename worked as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced the issue on my own project and the problem you face arise from the use of **secure_filename** function. According to [werkzeug documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/werkzeug.secure_filename.html) the function secure_filename will replace any whitespace of the user provided filename with an underscore. Adding some logging you might see that:

```py
f.filename # 'foo bar.png'
secure_filename(f.filename) # 'foo_bar.png'
```

So, when you call the **gcs_upload** function you're passing the original filename instead of the one returned by secure_filename and as the error message points out such file does not exist.

To solve the issue just change your upload function to:

```py
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(filename)
        gcs_upload(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to quote  filename (by using **urllib**) before. This is an example by using **python3**:

```
import urllib.parse
filename = "files name.jpg"
new_file = str(urllib.parse.quote(filename))
```